# Boost asio udp waitForReadyRead

Tags: sockets, boost, udp, timeout, boost-asio

I am trying to implement a function using boost asio udpSocket, that waits until data is ready to be read, or waits until a timeout expires.

using asyc_read and a async_wait, I can do something similar, but I have to read the data. I would like to do the same ***without reading the data***

This would allow a much easier use of the udpSocket class in many situations, but given the the udpSocket interface, I cannot figure out how to implement such a function, without manually buffering the data, and rewriting a sync_read function

best, Dd

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `async_receive` ([link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_receive/overload2.html)) using the option `message_peek` ([link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/message_peek.html)).  That way you can set up a timeout-bound read like you were wanting, but without pulling any data off of the receive buffer.

For more details, read the [MSDN description of MSG_PEEK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740121%28VS.85%29.aspx) (which is the Windows-specific implementation of `message_peek`...you need to scroll down to the bottom of the article).  That should give you a good idea of how it works in more detail, though you should consult your system's documentation to be absolutely certain.